# famo.us access to collisionData upon collision event

Tags: javascript, famo.us, physics-engine

In the famo.us source I see that two things are emitted upon collision: the 'collision' string, and a variable called collisionData, like this: (physics/constraints/Collision.js, lines 112-122):

```
if (this._eventOutput) {
                var collisionData = {
                    target  : target,
                    source  : source,
                    overlap : overlap,
                    normal  : n
                };

                this._eventOutput.emit('preCollision', collisionData);
                this._eventOutput.emit('collision', collisionData);
            }
```

I know how to use the 'collision' string like so:

```
collision.on('collision', function() {
  // do stuff
};
```

But, it would be very helpful to know target and source for a collision event.  How do I get access to collisionData?  collision.collisionData returns 'undefined'.

Comment: It's passed as the first parameter to your callback function (probably).

Comment: Thanks Evan!  `collision.on('collision', function(collisionData) { console.log(collisionData) }; ` will show the collision data.  Unfortunately if doesn't give me agent id's or some other unique object identifier, unless I'm missing something.  Back to the drawing board...

Comment: Just had a look at the API documentation, it's pretty useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the object from the return event object:

```js
collision.on('collision', function(data) {
  // do stuff
  console.log('data', data);
  console.log('target', data.target);
  console.log('source', data.source);
});
```

The `target` and `source` returned are the particles of the body objects you attached to create collision.

**[Example Code here](http://jsbin.com/xukewa/1/edit?js,output)** (not tested fully)

Just do something like the following to track a unique id of who bumped together.

```js
// assuming your body is called body and body1 respectively
//   also, this is just partial code.
var uniqueID = 0;
body.particle = new Circle({
  radius: 50,
  position: [x, y, 0]
});
body1.particle = new Circle({
  radius: 50,
  position: [x, y, 0]
});

body.particle.uniqueID = 'body' + uniqueID;
uniqueID += 1;
body1.particle.uniqueID = 'body' + uniqueID;
```

```js
collision.on('collision', function(data) {
  // do stuff
  console.log('target id', data.target.uniqueID);
  console.log('source id', data.source.uniqueID);
});
```